# twig/symfony, need db data on every page extending my twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Alright, Let's try and explain my current knowledge and problems.

I have some data in my database, that I want to use in my `root.html.twig` template (and thus every template extending it.

First think I thought of was a simple database call, but after some googling and reading up on AppExtension's the common opinion seems to be that it is bad practice.

Now, I could just call and pass the data every time I call a page. This would however lead to adding it in almost every controller I would write.

The only thing I can think of now is writing a custom handler to render the template, and inject the needed data in there. (hope that explanation makes sense).

Any pointers to stuff to read up on, or advice for different routes to take would be greatly appreciated (:

Kinda regards,
Daneel

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not render an embedded controller?

Comment: hey, thought I was kinda clear in the original post. In any case, embedded controllers were indeed the solution. I just wasn't aware of them before @sander-voogt pointed me toward them. I've solved it tho (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render a controller directly in your twig view.

```
   {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\HomeController::footerLocations')) }}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#embedding-controllers

Comment: wauw, that seems to be exactly what I was looking for.
thanks!

Comment: Eww this seems really nasty. Each to their own but injecting from controller or Twig calling a custom Twig Extension seems much cleaner